# How to handle ListView's scroll event and my own OnTouch methods paralelly?

Tags: android, listview, events, touch

I have a `ListView`, and an `onTouchListener` on the `RealitveLayout` inside the `ListView`. It's working great, I get the touch coordinates, as long as I don't start scrolling, because `ListView` "steals" the touch event from my `OnTouchEvent` method, and it calls `ACTION_CANCEL`. If I set `requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)` on my `ListView`, my `OnTouchEvent` method works great, it tracks the movement well, but the `ListView` wont scroll. How can I achieve, that both the `ListView` scroll, and my method get the event?
Here is the relevant code: (the `touch()` method is called from an adapter, on a `RelativeLayout`, and the `ListView` is initialized in the `onCreate()` method of this activity)

```
@Override
public void touch(MotionEvent event) {
    int x = (int) event.getX();
    int y = (int) event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            Log.i("TAG", "touched down");
            FriendlyTouch friendlyTouch = new FriendlyTouch(true, x, y, key);
            mMessagesDatabaseReference2.setValue(friendlyTouch);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            Log.i("TAG", "moving: (" + x + ", " + y + ")");
            FriendlyTouch friendlyTouch1 = new FriendlyTouch(true, x, y, key);
            mMessagesDatabaseReference2.setValue(friendlyTouch1);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            Log.i("TAG", "touched up");
            mMessagesDatabaseReference2.child("TouchDown").setValue(false);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_SCROLL: //this doesnt seem to do anything`
            Log.i(TAG, "scrolled");
            FriendlyTouch friendlyTouch2 = new FriendlyTouch(true, x, y, key);
            mMessagesDatabaseReference2.setValue(friendlyTouch2);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            Log.i(TAG, "cancelled");
            mMessagesDatabaseReference2.child("TouchDown").setValue(false);
            break;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the method "boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)" from your ontouchlistener return false? False should allow other listeners to get the touchEvent also. If you return true other touchlisteners will not be called.

Comment: It returns false, so ListView can steal the event, but I want to give it only a "copy" of the event, so it can scroll, while I can get the x,y coordinates of the touches

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could also build a `CustomListView` by extending `ListView`.
You then should override `onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)`, this method is responsible for canceling your onTouch-event and instead perform the scrolling (at least in my case).

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if(youWantScrollingToWork()){
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }else{
        //don`t scroll, instead continue your own touchEvent
        return false;
    }
}
```

If you really need both to work, I guess your only chance is to also override `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)` of the ListView and then make it return false, so your listener still gets called, but that seems rather nasty.